# iphone multiple views

Tags: iphone, view

i need to get 3 views for an iphone App. Each view should contain several icons . when i swipe the first view it should take me to the second view(which also has several icons). see the below image to get an idea.
[image]

at the bottom it has 3 dots which tells the user that there are 3 screens to swipe. what is this called. This is just like the our normal apps in the iphone. when i swipe it should take me to the next screen with different icons.

i was not able to figure out what kind of view controller it is and how to implement it. i just need some idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be pretty simply done by Interface Builder.

1. Create 3 Views
2. The Icons can be implemented by Round Rect Buttons
3. The "Dots" are a "Page Control"
4. Set the IBOutlets and delegates and you are done

Answer (score 0):

First, read the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

The 3 dots are [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006781)
Icon grid is not in standard control... You can see the [three20 project](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) to do this (but before using a 3rd part resource, try to do manually)